# Requiring user password authentication for JMX on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis, jconsole

Where in the configuration do you enable/disable authentication for JMX in Artemis? In the `artemis.profile` file I have `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` on two instances of Artemis, one on a local VM and one on a remote VM. The local one doesn't require authentication (such as from JConsole) and will fail if I give is the user/password. The remote instance requires authentication, which accepts the user/password I created when setting up Artemis.

Is there another configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis guards JMX calls using [role based authentication](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#role-based-authorisation-for-jmx) that leverages Artemis's JAAS plugin support with the ***login.config*** file. This is configured via the authorisation element in the ***management.xml*** configuration file and can be used to restrict access to attributes and methods on mbeans.

Comment: I see. In login.config I have org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required for the instance needing authentication, and "sufficient" for the one now. I think this is due to the setup step that asks if you'd like to allow anonymous access.